# Form validation, make exception for a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to validate a specific form field so that, for example, a user can enter values between 1 and 100; but if the field is left empty, it will automatically  input -1 instead.

My code is stopping -1 from being submitted because it is not between 1 and 100, it seems.

Here's an example:

```
var x = document.getElementById('test').value;

if(x !== '') {  
    if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 100) {
        feedback = feedback + "Input value must be between 1 and 100.\n";
    }
}

else {
    document.getElementById('test').value = "-1";
}
```

When the form is submitted I get the alert as above:

> Input value must be between 1 and 100.

Because it enters -1 and won't submit with that value.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to test that specific case *before* testing the positive-number range:

```
if (isNaN(x) || (x != -1 && (x < 1 || x > 100))) {
```

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the if statement your using is only setting the `document.getElementById('test').value = "-1";` if `x !== ''`

Meaning that if the x variable is a number it is never being set to -1

I would also set the value in second if statement like below

```
var x = document.getElementById('test').value;

        if(x !== '') {

            if (isNaN(x) || x < 1 || x > 100) {
                feedback = feedback + "Input value must be between 1 and 100.\n";
                document.getElement('test').value = -1;

            }
        }

        else {
            document.getElementById('test').value = "-1";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The if statement is only setting the value to "-1" if `x !== ''` (i.e. the field is left empty by the user) which is what is intended however, the form won't submit with the value -1 as it is not within the 1 - 100 range. Is there a way around this so it can submit with -1 as the input?